# Merge each entry of a list nested inside a tuple with the other part of the tuple

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, monocle-scala

I have a list (let's call it `L1`) of tuples, in this tuple `_1` is some class with data and `_2` is a list (let's call it `L2`) of some other classes with other data. For each entry of `L1` (that is a list of tuples) I need to merge each entry of `L2` with the corresponding `_1`. I am trying to compose a lens, but getting stuck. Here's a code snippet to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
  case class LiveData(information: String)
  case class StoredData(uniqueId: String)
  case class MergedData(uniqueId: String, information: String)

  def merge(live: LiveData, stored: StoredData): MergedData = MergedData(stored.uniqueId, live.information)
  
  type Data = (LiveData, List[StoredData])
  type UpdatedData = (LiveData, List[MergedData])
  
  def process(dataEntries: List[Data]): List[UpdatedData] = {
    val stored = GenLens[Data](_._2).each
    val live = GenLens[Data](_._1)
    val composed = ???
    ???
  }
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
def process(dataEntries: List[Data]): List[UpdatedData] = {
  val someLens = ???  
  someLens.each.modify(merge)(dataEntries)
}
```

Am I going in the right direction? Should I somehow try to compose these two lenses or do I need something completely different? I also use Cats in my project, but I'm very new to that and can't see at this time if it could be of any use in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

This type-checks and compiles.

```
def merge(dataEntries: List[Data]): List[UpdatedData] =
  dataEntries.map{ 
    case (ld, sds) =>
      (ld, sds.map(sd => MergedData(sd.uniqueId, ld.information)))
  }
```

If this isn't what you're looking for then perhaps you could be a bit more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question to be more specific, hope it's a bit more clear what I'm trying to achieve. Let me know if it looks like some additional information is still required